# Grouping for website pages on google search

Tags: facebook, seo, google-search

I have a website slateone.com, When I search slateone.com on google it gives me a search result with a group of links together as a single search. Whereas when I search for slateone it gives me the same links separately without any grouping.

I tried testing the same kind of search for popular websites like facebook and google shows same group search result for both facebook.com and facebook.

Please guide me on this issue.

Thanks in Advance!!

-Vinay

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are actually referring to sitelinks, they are completely automated and not editable.

Now your website first of all needs to have the title attribute in the  tags defined, this will surely help the algorithm of Google to find them, but note that does not mean that this is the solution.

The exact algorithm is known only to Google, the fix i mentioned will make the links more readable for the bots, this will surely help.

The official information can be found here: https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/47334?hl=en